# C++11 - What is the difference between CTOR() = default and empty CTOR(){}?

Tags: c++, c++11

C++11 introduced new keyword `default` to force creation of default constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass() = default; // <==
    MyClass(int num);
};
```

I could not find the reason to use it over empty constructor.

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass() {} // <==
    MyClass(int num);
};
```

Could anybody enlighten me?

Answer (score 7):

The `= default;` constructor is [trivial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Trivial_default_constructor), which no user provided constructor ever is - even an empty one.

Comment: It might be also be important to note that a `= default;` constructor is `constexpr` and/or `noexcept` by default if it is possible.